# how can i transform the needed field from an atom feed into an xml?

Tags: xml, xslt, atom-feed

I have an atom feeds with lots of information and I would like to transform the needed information into an XML. The java code is already done, but I can not create the stylesheet for this tranformation.

```
<feed version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:wwe="http://release.wwe.com/atom/1.0">
      <id>http://release.wwe.com/wweatomfeed.atom</id>
      <title><![CDATA[WWE Syndication Feed]]></title>
      <subtitle>WWE Feed to syndicate WWE assets to domestic as well as international partners. This feed has custom modules for accommodating custom data transfer to clients.</subtitle>
      <author><![CDATA[Roxy.Noordeen@wwecorp.com]]></author>
      <icon>http://release.wwe.com/media/storage_images/wwe-icon.jpg</icon>
      <logo>http://release.wwe.com/media/storage_images/wwe-logo.jpg</logo>
      <rights>2011 World Wrestling Entertainment!</rights>
      <entry>
        <id>26168987_26169027</id>
        <title><![CDATA[WrestleMania 31]]></title>
        <updated>2015-03-29T19:00:00-0400</updated>
        <category term="WrestleMania"/>
        <wwe:asset_type>Article</wwe:asset_type>
        <author><![CDATA[john clapp]]></author>
        <published>2015-03-29T19:00:00-0400</published>
        <content><![CDATA[
    Complete WrestleMania 31 coverage, news, videos, photos and more.
    ]]></content>
        <wwe:shortSummary/>
        <wwe:body><![CDATA[

    ]]></wwe:body>
        <wwe:breadCrumb>Homepage#Shows#Wrestlemania#31</wwe:breadCrumb>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <id>26663863_26663903</id>
        <title><![CDATA[WWE TLC 2014]]></title>
        <updated>2014-12-14T20:00:00-0500</updated>
        <category term="WWE TLC: Tables, Ladders and Chairs ... and Stairs"/>
        <wwe:asset_type>Article</wwe:asset_type>
        <author><![CDATA[john clapp]]></author>
        <published>2014-12-14T20:00:00-0500</published>
        <content><![CDATA[
    WWE TLC: Tables, Ladders, and Chairs … and Stairs 2014 takes over Cleveland's Quicken Loans Arena on Sunday, Dec. 14, at 8 p.m. ET/5 p.m. PT.
    ]]></content>
        <wwe:shortSummary/>
        <wwe:body><![CDATA[

    ]]></wwe:body>
        <wwe:breadCrumb>Homepage#Shows#Wwetlc#2014</wwe:breadCrumb>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <id>26898092_26898132</id>
        <title><![CDATA[The Most Shocking Tables, Ladders & Chairs Moments]]></title>
        <updated>2014-12-09T16:33:00-0500</updated>
        <category term="Non-Branded"/>
        <wwe:asset_type>Video</wwe:asset_type>
        <link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://us.wwe.com/f/video/thumb/2014/12/cdown_tlc_moments_updatedlogo.jpg"/>
        <link rel="enclosure" type="video/x-flv" href="http://release.wwe.com/media/storage_video/26898092.flv"/>
        <link rel="enclosure" type="video/mp4" href="http://release.wwe.com/media/storage_video/26898092.f4v"/>
        <link rel="enclosure" type="video/x-ms-wmv" href="http://release.wwe.com/media/storage_video/26898092.wmv"/>
        <link rel="enclosure" type="video/h264" href="http://release.wwe.com/media/storage_video/26898092.mp4"/>
        <content><![CDATA[The Most Shocking Tables, Ladders & Chairs Moments]]></content>
        <wwe:eventDate>2014-12-09T16:33:00-05:00</wwe:eventDate>
        <wwe:releaseDate>2014-12-09T16:33:00-05:00</wwe:releaseDate>
        <wwe:aspectRatio>
        </wwe:aspectRatio>
        <wwe:hours>0</wwe:hours>
        <wwe:minutes>3</wwe:minutes>
        <wwe:seconds>2</wwe:seconds>
        <wwe:breadCrumb>Homepage#Videos#The-most-shocking-tables-ladders-chairs-moments-26898092</wwe:breadCrumb>
      </entry>
      </feed>
```

**stylesheet used:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:wwe="http://release.wwe.com/atom/1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/atom:feed/atom:entry[wwe:asset_type='Video']"/>       
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- this template will delete the target nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="/atom:feed/atom:entry[wwe:asset_type='Video']/atom:id|/atom:feed/atom:entry[wwe:asset_type='Video']/atom:updated|/atom:feed/atom:entry[wwe:asset_type='Video']/atom:category"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**result:**

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:wwe="http://release.wwe.com/atom/1.0">
<title>The Most Shocking Tables, Ladders &amp; Chairs Moments</title>
<category term="Non-Branded"/>
<wwe:asset_type>Video</wwe:asset_type>
<link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://us.wwe.com/f/video/thumb/2014/12/cdown_tlc_moments_updatedlogo.jpg"/>
<link rel="enclosure" type="video/x-flv" href="http://release.wwe.com/media/storage_video/26898092.flv"/>
<link rel="enclosure" type="video/mp4" href="http://release.wwe.com/media/storage_video/26898092.f4v"/>
<link rel="enclosure" type="video/x-ms-wmv" href="http://release.wwe.com/media/storage_video/26898092.wmv"/>
<link rel="enclosure" type="video/h264" href="http://release.wwe.com/media/storage_video/26898092.mp4"/>
<content>The Most Shocking Tables, Ladders &amp; Chairs Moments</content>
<wwe:eventDate>2014-12-09T16:33:00-05:00</wwe:eventDate>
<wwe:releaseDate>2014-12-09T16:33:00-05:00</wwe:releaseDate>
<wwe:aspectRatio/>
<wwe:hours>0</wwe:hours>
<wwe:minutes>3</wwe:minutes>
<wwe:seconds>2</wwe:seconds>
<wwe:breadCrumb>Homepage#Videos#The-most-shocking-tables-ladders-chairs-moments-26898092</wwe:breadCrumb>
</entry>
```

**what I actually need:**

```
<rss xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:wwe="http://release.wwe.com/atom/1.0">
    <channel>
        <title><![CDATA[WWE Syndication Feed]]></title>
        <link>http://release.wwe.com/wweatomfeed.atom</link>
        <description>WWE Feed to syndicate WWE assets to domestic as well as international partners. This feed has custom modules for accommodating custom data transfer to clients</description>
        <rights>2011 World Wrestling Entertainment!</rights>

        <item>
            <title>The Most Shocking Tables, Ladders &amp; Chairs Moments</title>
            <category term="Non-Branded"/>
            <media:group>
                <media:content type="video/mp4" url="http://release.wwe.com/media/storage_video/26898092.f4v"/>
                <media:content type="image/jpeg" url="http://us.wwe.com/f/video/thumb/2014/12/cdown_tlc_moments_updatedlogo.jpg"/>
            </media:group>
        </item>

        <item>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: I have one more question, what should I change, if I don't need all the data from every entry, just for example  the links and the title?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your input, your desired output and what have you tried so far. Please do not try to edit answers.

Comment: sorry, I edited the question and removed from your comment

Comment: I hope my edited answer is final.

Comment: Sorry, I did not test my code for multiple matched nodes. Check again my edited post.

Comment: it is working nicely, but if there are more entries with video all is messed up, it shows first all the title, then all of the links. Can it be grouped? and also is it possible to transform the rows like :<link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://us.wwe.com/f/video/thumb/2014/11/20141110_Thumb_RAW_swagger.jpg"/>   to :   <media:content type="video/mp4" url="http://us.wwe.com/f/video/thumb/2014/11/20141110_Thumb_RAW_swagger.jpg"/>

Comment: Cool, it works I just have a final question, is it possible to transform the rows as: <link rel="enclosure" type="video/mp4" href="http://release.wwe.com/media/storage_video/26896433.f4v"/> to be like :  <media:content type="video/mp4" url="http://release.wwe.com/media/storage_video/26896433.f4v"/>

Comment: Thanks you, everything is working, I just can not rename the wwe:releaseDate tag tu pubDate tag because it always ads a namespace to it as attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this simple stylesheet would answer your problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:wwe="http://release.wwe.com/atom/1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:media="wwww.yourmedia.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="atom"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <rss xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
            <xsl:element name="title" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
            <xsl:element name="link" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
            <xsl:element name="description" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="/atom:feed/atom:entry[*[local-name()='asset_type'][.='Video']]">
                <xsl:element name="item" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="atom:title"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="atom:category"/>
                    <xsl:if test="atom:link">
                        <media:group>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="atom:link[@type='video/mp4']"/>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="atom:link[@type='image/jpeg']"/>
                        </media:group>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </rss>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="atom:link">
       <media:content>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='rel')]"/>
       </media:content>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but in this case it returns : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: In that case you can use `omit-xml-declaration="yes"` in xsl:output. See my modified answer.

Comment: Please see this link (http://www.xpathtester.com/xslt/0d0ff0ff8a3fe980d5044b1b461af674). I have tried your input against the stylesheet. You can view the results there.

Comment: it is working, there was problem with the java code, thanks a lot

Comment: I have one more question, what should I change, if I don't need all the data from every entry, just for example  the links and the title?

Comment: nice one, thanks, but one more question: every entry starts now with row: <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:wwe="http://release.wwe.com/atom/1.0"> can it be done the way that this row should  be visible just at the beginning of the xml, and no more?

Comment: you can just add a `root` node for the namespace declarations to be put there.

Comment: sorry, I added some comments to your, hope you can help with it, if not thanks for helping with the other stuff

Answer (score 0):

try out this

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl wwe test atom"
                xmlns:test="http://test.com/atom/1.0"
                xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
                xmlns:wwe="http://release.wwe.com/atom/1.0"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <good>
      <xsl:for-each select="atom:feed/atom:entry">
        <assettype>
          <xsl:if test="test:asset_type='VIDEO'">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="wwe:asset_type='VIDEO'">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="test:asset_type='Video'">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="wwe:asset_type='Video'">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </assettype>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </good>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you xml is invalid cause "wwe" prefix hasn't been defined.
That is why i have assumed that is exists in you xml by using the following namespace "Check".
This will vary for your xml but you will have to change the xslt namespace portion accordingly

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, I updated the feed, there were some errors in, but when I applied your stylesheet, the result was just:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><good xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>

Comment: I have updated it again and hence please check again with the updated one.

Comment: unfortunatelly I'm getting the same result:                                                           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><good xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>

Comment: kindly post your xslt.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is working to, just had error in the java code Thanks a lot

Comment: I have one more question, what should I change, if I don't need all the data from every entry, just for example the links and the title?

Comment: instead of this---"<xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>"
do this:"<title><xsl:copy-of select="title"/></title>"